# iOS filesharing, can't write to Document folder

Tags: c++, ios, file-io

Hi I'm finding myself unable to write to a file on ios. Here is the path:

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Application supports iTunes file sharing is set to YES.

/var/mobile/Applications/BB0464AB-2F13-4B23-81BF-FBA0D5A40D9A/MyApp.app/Documents/a.txt

```
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("/var/mobile/Applications/BB0464AB-2F13-4B23-81BF-FBA0D5A40D9A/MyApp.app/Documents/a.txt");
        myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
        myfile.close();


        string line;
        ifstream myfile2 ("/var/mobile/Applications/BB0464AB-2F13-4B23-81BF-FBA0D5A40D9A/MyApp.app/Documents/a.txt");
        if (myfile2.is_open())
        {
            while ( myfile2.good() )
            {
                getline (myfile2,line);
                cout << line << endl;
            }
            myfile2.close();
        } else std::cout << "Unable to open file";
```

Comment: What error/failure do you get?

Comment: After hours I figured it out -- the 'MyApp.app' should be stripped like ... FBA0D5A40D9A/Documents/a.txt

Comment: I think this will break if your app's UUID (the part of your path starting `BB...`) ever changes.

Comment: It would be great to know for sure.  It would seem very strange if they didn't give access to the /Documents/ folder in the app, gave it in the UUID path and then displayed the UUID path one in iTunes as well... Shouldn't it only display the non UUID one if thats the true path?